# How to change VS 2019 opening "splash screen" color theme

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2019, color-scheme

I have downloaded the "Solarized Dark Theme" from the VS Marketplace. In the screen dump shown below it's quite clear that the backgroundcolor is not set on the startup/welcome screen. What setting can I change to set that background-color to match my theme from the marketplace?

[image: vs2019 splash screen, screen dump]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press continue without code or open some projet.
In status bar:
facilities -> environment -> common -> color theme

[image: this]